# use of special characters in if statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm unfamiliar with bash scripting. I wrote a script check arguments. the code is:

```
for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ ))
do
        if ! [[ "$"$i =~ .*[^0-9].* ]]; then
                echo "bad input was $i"
        fi
done
```

Actually i want to split non numerical arguments, But it seems that "$"$i is wrong because the answer is always true or false independent of arguments.
can anybody tell me what is the mistake?

Comment: "the answer is always true or false" -- well, what else should a boolean be? (Also, don't you have to quote the RHS?)

Comment: i mean it is unchangeable in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If condition should be like this:

```
if [[ ! "$i" =~ [^0-9] ]]; then
```

OR remove 2 negatives:

```
if [[ "$i" =~ [0-9] ]]; then
```

OR use glob:

```
if [[ "$i" == *[0-9]* ]]; then
```

Which means `$i` contains a digit `0-9`

**Update:** Based on your comments it looks like you are looking for BASH variable indirection like this script `check-num.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
    [[ "${!i}" != *[0-9]* ]] && echo "bad input was ${!i}"
done
```

You can run this script as: `./check-num.sh 1 2 x 4 a`

Note how `${!i}` syntax is being used here to access the variable's `$1, $2, $3` etc that is called BASH variable indirection. *You shouldn't use `$$i` for this purpose.*

As per BASH manual:

> `If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point, a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from
>          the  rest  of  parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the
>          value of parameter itself.`

Comment: unfortunately not working. have you tried it so far?
condition is always true when i run it like fs.sh 1 2 3 4 
output is for messages of bad inputs. consider that i need it to be a number not containing a digit.

Comment: Try this script in your BASH shell and let me know what you get in output: **`for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ )); do [[ "$i" == *[0-9]* ]] && echo "numeric"; done`**

Comment: my script name is 2_3.sh  when i run 2_3.sh 1 2 3 4 there is nothing in output. it seems the first condition `[[ "$i" ..]]` is always false.

Comment: Post your script in your question, I believe there is some simple problem

Comment: And please be prompt in your responses as its pretty late here.

Comment: `for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ )); do [[ "si" == *[0-9]* ]] && echo "numeric"; done`

Comment: You have **`"si"`** instead of **`"$i"`** (letter `s` instead of dollar sign)

Comment: urh.. i'm so sorry you are right. now there is numeric in output but the problem is not fixed. no matter what argument i pass there is always numeric in output.

Comment: If there is even one digit in input it will print numeric. Test this: `[[ "abc" == *[0-9]* ]] && echo "numeric"` now it won't print `numeric`

Comment: No i have tested it, but it prints numeric anyway. I think you have misunderstood the question. my problem is the way `"$i"` parse. In fact i need to test argument not e simple number (`$i`). got it?
I need something like `$$i` but it is not working. because it means current bash process then a single `i`. Is that true?

Comment: Now fro comment it is becoming clear what you wanted to achieve. Wish you had written it clearly in your question. Let me update my answer to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to use indirect parameter expansion.

```
for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ ))
do
    if ! [[ ${!i} =~ .*[^0-9].* ]]; then
        echo "bad input was $i"
    fi
done
```

However, it's cleaner to just iterate over the parameters directly, rather than over their position:

```
for arg in "${@:1:4}"; do
    if ! [[ $arg =~ .*[^0-9].* ]]; then
        echo "bad input was $arg"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this :

```
for i in "$@"; do
     [[ $i =~ .*[^0-9].* ]] || echo "bad input was $i"
done
```

N.B : It's not necessary to use doubles quotes arround the variable with the [[ internal instruction.

Comment: `shift` will remove the first 4 parameters from `$@`.